# kdb+ 32-bit, what are the consequences of the 4GB restriction?

Tags: database-connection, port, 32bit-64bit, kdb

I'm trying out [kdb+](http://kx.com/kdb-plus.php) and I found out that the most common way to communicate with a program is to open a socket on port 5001 like so:

```
q -p 5001
```

Now kdb+ has built-in functionality for multi-threading called [peach](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/peach). According to their documentation, from version v3.1 peach will automatically:

> Since v3.1, peach can use multiple processes instead of threads,
>   configured through the startup cmd line option -s with a negative
>   integer, i.e. -s -N, e.g. -s -4. On startup, kdb+ will then try to
>   connect to N processes on **ports 20000 through 20000+N-1**, and use of
>   peach with >1 element will use those processes to execute the function
>   given to peach.

I was wondering, could I also do this manually?

I am currently running the 32-bit version of kdb+ (up to 4GB of memory per process) and according to [this post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/is-there-any-thing-out-there-as-a-substitute-for-kdb/11029#11029), you can work around the 4GB restriction by using a multiprocessing system.

So what exactly does *multiprocessing* mean? Do I need to start *N* instances of kdb+ on different ports (like peach) to get a *N* x 4GB in-memory application or is the 4GB limit simply a restriction on something else?

*So on what exactly is this 4GB a restriction?* Do I need to open multiple ports?

### Edit

[This website](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/interprocess-communication) seems to confirm that for multiple processes and inter-process communication, I need to open multiple ports on different addresses.

So is each **instance** of kdb+ considered to be ***a process*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, a kdb+ instance is a whole process in its own right, with a port number set at command line by yourself.

You can't do peach over a number of handles:

```
handles:hopen each someList;
{x"do some work"} peach handles
```

You'll get `noupdate`, so would seem you can't do this manually. There is a handshake on `hopen` so even if there are other processes running on that port range, kdb would know which ones are kdb (I guess it would capture an error on `hopen`... but I've never tried it)

Comment: Perfectly explains it. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you happen to know where the 4GB limit stems from? Is it an imposed restriction or does it have something to do with the process being 32-bit?

Comment: It's because it's a binary for 32bit. If you want 64 bit, it's no longer free.

Comment: I know that, but is it so that *because* it is a 32bit, there is a 4GB restriction or is this an imposed restriction by kx for the free version?

Comment: it is not an imposed restriction (by kx). It can only address 4GB because it is 32bit binary.

Answer (score 0):

Really restriction is 1GB RAM for variables and tables. Not 4GB.